# How do I get deploy-war to work using jetty 9 maven plugin?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, jetty-9

In jetty-9 the `mvn jetty:deploy-war` fails to start the web application. Maven just ends the build, while I expect it to block with a running jetty server. According to the logging output the jetty maven plugin does start a connector on port 8080, and it starts the WebAppContext. It seems to fail binding the port to the context though.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a web app: `mvn archetype:generate -DinteractiveMode=false -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DgroupId=jetty -DartifactId=jetty-demo`

Add this plugins-section to the pom:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Execute:

`mvn package`

`mvn jetty:deploy-war`  This should start the web app and then block, but it just ends the build

Using jetty-8 all works fine:

```
<groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
```

Note: `mvn jetty:run-war` works as expected in jetty 9. This is the same as deploy-war, but it triggers jetty to build the war before deployment

Reference: [the jetty-9 maven plugin manual](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/jetty-maven-plugin.html#deploy-war-running-pre-assembled-war). And I debugged the jetty startup proces, but without luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation you linked to tells you why](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.10.v20150310/jetty-maven-plugin.html#deploy-war-running-pre-assembled-war).

Set the `daemon` parameter to `false` and it will block

Comment: Tried that before but now I see I had made a typo in 'daemon`. Important thing is that you explicitly need to set it to false in jetty-9. Thx